# Good references for mathematics of sound attenuation?

Tags: acoustics, resource-recommendations, models

I am looking for recommendations for good references for mathematical modeling of [sound attenuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_attenuation).

Comment: Could you be more specific about what type of book you are looking for? For example, what level of a book do you want (e.g., high school, college, etc), what background do you have (math, physics, etc), any specific subject matter, and so on?

Comment: My background is in electrical engineering, physics and mathematics. I am working on a mathematical model that requires a module that addresses attenuation of low frequency noise sources (specifically noise from custom exhaust systems and heavy bass stereo).  This will be used to support the evaluation of some proposed changes to local and state law (very significant increase in noise complaints).  Primarily to simulate and supply parameters to make the revised changes actionable and less ambiguous for law enforcement. So at least at the college level or graduate level.

Comment: Withdraw the question - will consult other sources.